# React - setting one item from parent's state as child's state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a React newbie and trying to learn it by building a simple quote generator where a quote is generated depending on the mood a user selects. The App component holds the state: quotes and moods (where each element is a nested object) and its children are Mood components.

Now, the state of the App component consists of four moods and what I would like to happen is: when a user clicks a button inside the Mood component, s/he is redirected to that mood's page and the Mood component's state is set to that particular mood.

The solution I worked out by myself is very crude and I'm looking for a way to make it more elegant/functional.

Here is the moods object that is the App's state:

```
const moods = {
    mood1: {
        type: 'upset',
        image: 'abc.png',
    },
    mood2: {
        type: 'unmotivated',
        image: 'abc.png',
    },
    mood3: {
        type: 'anxious',
        image: 'abc.png',
    },
}
```

the App component:

```
state ={
  moods: moods,
}



  render(){
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <ul className='moods'>
      {
        Object.keys(this.state.moods).map(key => <Mood
          moodsData = {this.state.moods}
          key={key}
          indexKey = {key}
          index={this.state.moods[key].type}
          details={this.state.moods[key]}
          />)
      }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );}}
```

And this is how far I got inside the Mood component, where the onClick function on the button is:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
this.setState({moods: e.target.value});
}
```

I will be grateful for any pointers/suggestions! Spent so many hours on this I feel like my brain doesn't accept any more Youtube tutorials/Medium articles.

Comment: What I would suggest is that state should be set at App component level using a prop as a function which will be invoked by handleClick function on nested component.

Comment: Hey! what you are trying to do is called props, where you pass a value from the parent to the children, and that value can be states, and it will mutate with the parents changes too.

Comment: Hey, thank you Vimal and Sebastian!
Sebastian, you are absolutely right, I did it already and it worked wonderfully - my problem is because the state is a nested object and I only need a chunk of it to be a child's state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the first thing i notice is that you are trying to use map on a javascript object instead of an array, this could bring some problems when using some functions, so i advice to make it an array.

If you just have one Mood component and based on the mood type it receives change its style, it doesn't actually need to manage state from inside, you can just pass the props to the Mood component and work around what props receives.

For example:

Moods as an array:

```
const moods = [
  {
      type: 'upset',
      image: 'abc.png',
  },
  {
      type: 'unmotivated',
      image: 'abc.png',
  },
  {
      type: 'anxious',
      image: 'abc.png',
  },
]
```

i'm assuming you get the Mood list from a server or an external source so that's why i'm keeping moods in state instead of just mapping through the const moods.

```
state ={
    moods: moods,
    mood:null,
  }

  onClick= (key) =>{
    console.log(this.state.moods[key]);
    this.setState({
      mood:this.state.moods[key],
    })
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="Container">
        <ul className='moods'>
        {
          Object.keys(this.state.moods).map((key) => <div key={key}>
            <a onClick={() =>{this.onClick(key)}}>Click here to change the mood to {this.state.moods[key].type}</a>
          </div>)
        }
        </ul>
        {this.state.mood ? <Mood actualMood={this.state.mood}/> : null}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and the Mood component just gets some props and display something based on what it gets:

```
class Mood extends Component 
{
  render() 
  {
    console.log(this.props.actualMood.type);
    return (
      <div>
       <p>You're looking at {this.props.actualMood.type} mood</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this can be easily achieved using react hooks but class based components need a tricky solution and may not look easy at first glance.

If what you want to achieve is to move to another component, you can have a parent Component which only manages the state, then based on a condition (if mood has been selected) render a component either ChooseAMoodComponent or MoodComponent.

Another way to achieve this is through React Router which you can pass some params via URL get params.

but the best practice should be using Redux.

Comment: I used Object.keys on it before mapping though...
Thank you for your response, I'll work my way through it :)

Comment: Okay, I think perhaps the way I explained my problem was unclear as the terminology is often tricky for me but nonetheless I used bits of your suggestion and it was a great help, thank you Jason :)